# Is there a way to ensure template argument is a container?

Tags: c++, templates

What are mechanisms for ensuring that template arguments are containers?

Alternatively, how can i make different specialisations for class/function depending on whether its argument is container or not?

Comment: Any container or standard library containers?

Comment: Why? The whole point is that you should not care. Let the instantiation work for as long as the correct functions are available. Otherwise you go down a dark and dangerous path of "only _I_ get to choose which types are 'correct'"

Comment: What do you call a container?  Does a container own its contents?

Comment: You may use a concept check for this. In c++11 there are a number of static (compile time) check methods to realize such concept check.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Down that path you get `std::function` which can be constructed from anything (well, not really, but its signature lets it!): this prevents other functions from having two overloads, one of which takes a `std::function<bool()>`, the other takes a `std::function<void()>`.  Being able to restrict your arguments with a test that isn't "does this function compile" is useful: such tests can enable SFINAE, and hence sensible overloading.

Comment: What would be any container? For example, if we say that any type with operator [] is a container - then maybe i would like to differentiate between them and standard library containers (or Qt containers, for example) as well.

Comment: You can use "static_asserts" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static_assert and other weird stuff to get compile time checks on types and whatnot, but it is usually easier and better to just document the template argument needs to do "foo". Else you are not using templates, you are using polymorphism.

Comment: @Yakk: Huh? SFINAE is precisely what I'm talking about.

Comment: i would like different specialisations for container and non-container arguments, if possible. for example, do_something() and the same in for_each

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Your first comment was consistent with "just use ducktyping, and let the template function fail to compile". A traits class and SFINAE would qualify as "a mechanism to ensure that a template argument is a container", which you dismissed as not required ("Why?").  Your previous comment was far from clear.  :)

Comment: @Yakk: Well, fair enough -- I guess I supposed that the question included the text "SFINAE on function calls is not good enough", but indeed it did not! The nuance is that a SFINAE solution doesn't guarantee that the arg is a container.. only that it _looks like one_ (and, frankly, what's the distinction?)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit if you would be so kind and post as answer instead of comment, i would be able to accept it

Comment: @Srv19: I haven't composed an answer.

Comment: @Srv19 Your comment really has my curiosity going. I'm curious to know what your use case is that would even allow for competing specializations - one requiring the template parameter to be a container, and the other allowing for it to be a non-container. When I've used specializations, it has always been to give special abilities to types of a similar nature: eg. Do one thing for floats and something else for ints. I could see you wanting to treat different types of containers differently, but to allow for containers versus non-containers sounds quite out of the ordinary.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Where do you see the difference of _using templates_ and use of (static) _polymorphism_? IMHO, the only (positive) difference for concept checks is, that a user can see useful compilation errors instead of usually weird and cryptic stuff, that need's a look at the documentation to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @g-makulik Its a semantic different: With dynamic polymorphism, you have an "isa" relationship, while with templates, you (typically) have a "quacks like a" relationship. So the idea is that if you have a template class that is checking that everything that uses it isa specific type, you probably could have gotten away with not using a template. Checking for the "quacks like a" gives you compile time checks that can be more readable than the garbage the compiler usually spews.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams And what's your point then here? Who was talking about _dynamic polymorphism_? You're just repeating my opinion in other words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing for a full blown container is difficult and ambiguous.  Personally, I consider something a *container* if and only if it owns its immediate contents, but this may not line up with other people's use of the term.

Testing for *iterability* is neither difficult nor ambiguous, and is often what you want to test for when taking an object in a function argument.  There are iterable things that aren't very container like (C++1y's or C++1z's `string_view`, as an example).

In my opinion, in C++11, an instance c of a type X is iterable iff:

```
for( auto&& a : c ) {}
```

is well formed.  The wording chosen for the above means that you can extend any type with `begin` and `end` free function overloads to make it iterable.

A decent approximation if the above will work would be to test if, in an argument dependent enabled lookup context, that `std::begin` and `std::end` return something that has a valid `std::iterator_traits<>`.

As a quick sketch, I get something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename=void>
struct is_iterable : std::false_type {};

namespace aux {
  using std::begin;
  // note: no implementation
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_begin( C&& c )->decltype( begin( std::forward<C>(c) ) );
  using std::end;
  // note: no implementation
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_end( C&& c )->decltype( end( std::forward<C>(c) ) );
}
template<typename T>
struct is_iterable<T,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
      typename std::iterator_traits< typename std::decay<decltype( aux::adl_begin( std::declval<T>() ) )>::type >::iterator_category,
      typename std::iterator_traits< typename std::decay<decltype( aux::adl_end( std::declval<T>() ) )>::type >::iterator_category
    >::value
  >::type
> : std::true_type {};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/Fw6R84)

Containers, meanwhile, rarely are as uniform.  Their most basic "common" processes, like adding elements, differ from one to another in ways that differ in signature and semantics.  `erase(iterator)` and `::allocator_type` are the two most common features of container-like structures, but a `std::array<T,N>` and `T[N]` are arguably containers and have neither property.

In short, beyond their common property of iterability, containers differ too much for there to be a highly useful `is_container<C>` traits class.  Instead, you should work out what properties of the container you are looking for (ability to delete elements?  Ability to insert elements?  Random access?) and test for those instead.

Comment: I should have specified ti before, but is there analogue to what you did for older versions of c++?

Comment: @Srv19 only marginally.  How do you intend to get the iterators for the iterable object without `std::begin` and `std::end`?  You could roll your own pseudo-`std::begin` and `std::end` that behaves similarly.  The other C++11 features I used `std::enable_if` and `std::declval` and `std::decay` are all equally easy to reimplement, and probably have a `boost` equivalent.

Comment: Your explanation is reasonable and helpful enough, and gives direction for mine further studies. Seems like i have to accept it )

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [boost::spirit::traits::is_container<>](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/is_container.html)

> Returns `mpl::true_` if `T` has the following embedded types defined: `value_type`, `iterator`, `size_type`, and `reference`. Otherwise it will return `mpl::false_`.

Works in C++03 and above.